# cocotb cannot load VPI module

Tags: cocotb

When trying to make the endian_swapper example code, I get the error message below. I am using Ubuntu 19.10.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
make SIM=ghdl TOPLEVEL_LANG=vhdl
make results.xml
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/Tools/cocotb-master/examples/endian_swapper/tests'
cd ../cosim && make
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/Tools/cocotb-master/examples/endian_swapper/cosim'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Tools/cocotb-master/examples/endian_swapper/cosim'
cd sim_build && \
 \
/usr/bin/ghdl -i    --work=work /home/user/Tools/cocotb-master/examples/endian_swapper/tests/../hdl/endian_swapper.vhdl && \
/usr/bin/ghdl -m    --work=work endian_swapper_vhdl
MODULE=test_endian_swapper,test_endian_swapper_hal \
        TESTCASE= TOPLEVEL=endian_swapper_vhdl TOPLEVEL_LANG=vhdl COCOTB_SIM=1 \
/usr/bin/ghdl -r   --workdir=sim_build --work=work endian_swapper_vhdl --vpi=/home/user/Tools/cocotb-master/cocotb/libs/libcocotbvpi_ghdl.so  
loading VPI module '/home/user/Tools/cocotb-master/cocotb/libs/libcocotbvpi_ghdl.so'
libcocotbutils.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ghdl-mcode:error: cannot load VPI module
make[1]: *** [/home/user/Tools/cocotb-master/cocotb/share/makefiles/simulators/Makefile.ghdl:69: results.xml] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Tools/cocotb-master/examples/endian_swapper/tests'
make: *** [/home/user/Tools/cocotb-master/cocotb/share/makefiles/Makefile.sim:151: sim] Error 2
```

all *.so files seem to be present though

```
user@Computer:~/Tools/cocotb-master/cocotb/libs$ ls
libcocotb.so            libcocotbvhpi_ius.so   libcocotbvpi_icarus.vpl   libcocotbvpi_vcs.so        libgpi.so
libcocotbutils.so       libcocotbvpi_aldec.so  libcocotbvpi_ius.so       libcocotbvpi_verilator.so
libcocotbvhpi_aldec.so  libcocotbvpi_ghdl.so   libcocotbvpi_modelsim.so  libgpilog.so
```

Comment: I found a workaround myself: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/Tools/cocotb-master/cocotb/libs/

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in cocotb that should be fixed now. Please see https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/pull/1606